# Postgres LIKE in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a Postgres `LIKE` statement like this:

```
@favorites.find_each do |profiles|
  @related_profiles = Profile.where('name LIKE ?', '%' + profiles.name + '%')
end
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through the `favourites` variable and find all profiles that `contain` some characters of the name.

For example a name `"jasson jackson"` should be found if the name contains `"jackson"` or `"jasson"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query you're looking for would be like:

```
Profile.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{profiles.name}%")
```

But note that your `@related_profiles` may not be properly assigned as the result would be the same as saying:

```
Profile.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{@favorites.last.name}%")
```

whereas, I doubt if that is what you need.
Also note that the it would be an ActiveRecord::Collection, an array like object.

A way to work around that is to initialize `@related_profiles = []` and then at each point through your loop, you could do:

```
@related_profiles += 
Profile.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{profiles.name}%")
```

or another way is:

```
names = @favorites.map(&:name)
query = names.map{|name| "name LIKE '%#{name}%'"}.join(" OR ")
```

OR

```
query = @favorites.map{|favorite| "name LIKE '%#{favorite.name}%'" }.join(" OR ")
```

THEN

```
profiles = Profile.where(query)
```

**UPDATE**
Based on a comment from @joshrumbut, I decided to reimplement using the bind parameters.
However, code clarity is a bit lost, but here's a way it could be done:

```
names = @favorites.map(&:name)
query = names.map{|favorite| "name LIKE ?" }.join(" OR ")
profiles = Profile.where(query, *names.map{|name| ("%#{name}%")})
```

Based on the comment from @muistooshort, I removed the quotes from the first two queries and I think this approach looks a bit cleaner, as he suggested. From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)

```
Profile.where('name like any(array[?])', names.map { |s| "%#{s}%" })
```

Comment: Great background on what's going wrong with the asker's approach, but I'm concerned about building a query with string concatenation like this. Using parameter binding as @Fist does below is the better practice here in my mind.

Comment: `where('name like any(array[?])', names.map { |s| "%#{s}%" })` is a cleaner option ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)). Also, the single quotes in first two aren't needed (and will cause problems) in the placeholder values, ActiveRecord will properly escape things for you.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort, the approach sure looks cleaner. Updating the answer to reflect these and attributing appropriately.

Comment: This still does not work, if I they variable is jason jackson and I'm searching for 'jackson' or just 'jason' this profile won't show only if its 'jason jackson' then the profile would load

Answer (score 1):

For better results with this type of search, You can try use FTS (Full text search).

Rails has a gem with this feature implemented:

https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search

> PgSearch builds named scopes that take advantage of PostgreSQL's full text search.

With this gem installed on your project, just use this statement for search:

```
PgSearch.multisearch("jasson")
```

Other option is **Elasticsearch**, with him you can  index yours registers for a better text search.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try with Postgres patterns and "OR" operator - [postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)

```
names = @favorites.map(&:name)
Profile.where('name LIKE %(?)%', names.join('|'))
```

Comment: LIKE doesn't understand the regex alternation operator, you'd need to use SIMILAR TO or `~` for that (and then you'd have to worry about escaping things that are special in regexes).